# Jquery Event Click não funciona na pré-visualização da imagem

Tags: javascript, html5

Clicar no elemento img não funciona para chamar uma função JS, o que estou fazendo de errado ?

Segue o código abaixo:

**HTML:**

```
<label class="control-label">Select File</label>
<input id="input-id" type="file" class="file">
```

**JS:**

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({
  showZoom: true,
  zoomIcon: false
});

//Tentativa 1
$("img[class='kv-preview-data file-preview-image']").on('click', function() {
  alert('addMore click event');
});

//Tentativa 2
$("img[class='kv-preview-data file-preview-image']").click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});

//Tentativa 3
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img[class='kv-preview-data file-preview-image']").click(function () {
    alert("Hello!");
  });
});

//Tentativa 4
$(".kv-file-content").on('click', function() {
  alert('addMore click event');
});
```

Nenhuma das 4 tentativas não funcionam. Segue exemplo [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30008/).

Segue a imagem onde deve clicar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".file-preview").on('click', "img[class='kv-preview-data file-preview-image']", function() {
  alert('addMore click event');
});
```

Tens de delegar esse evento uma vez que essa imagem ainda não existe quando corres o jQuery. Como estás a fazer o jQuery procura por `img[class='kv-preview-data file-preview-image']`, não encontra e não adiciona nada.

Usando `$(algoExistente).on(evento, delegado, function(){` ele vai procurar o `delegado` no momento do click dentro de `algoExistente`.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30009/